# Python requests library giving me a list error when trying to retrieve a value using a key

Tags: python, json, dictionary, python-requests

I am calling an endpoint

```
results = get(ENDPOINT, params=url_parameters).json()
```

and get the following JSON packet

```
{"status":"success","results":1,"data":[{"companyName":"International Business Machines Corporation","tradeName":"IBM","website":"ibm.com","timeZoneId":"America/New_York","timeZoneName":"Eastern Daylight Time","utcOffset":"-04:00","dstOffset":1,"confidence":77,"isISP":0,"isWifi":0,"isMobile":0}]}
```

I try and access the data like this

```
domain = results["data"]["website"]
```

and I get the following error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I am not sure why it is using a list rather than a dict and not sure how I can reference the data I am trying to retrieve any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`results['data']` is a list. What you need is `results['data'][0]['website']`

Comment: thankyou, that is very helpful and worked, I'm new to Python and still working out the data structures.